# How does this recursive functions work to produce all permutations?

Tags: python, recursion

I really struggle to understand recursive code. I have copied a block of code I am trying to understand. I have seen this described in a pictorial manner but I don't understand how the program gets to the result.

This is my understanding so far

**Initially**

- (ABC, 0, 3) is passed into the function
- If condition not met SO **enter the ELSE** branch
- j is 0 and i is 0 this time (swap first character with first
  character)
- **THEN* send new 'data' back into the function and re-reun Question
- **Why does "j" remain increment with i?** The for loop hasn't been run to completetion Anyway.... for some reason j and i both increase
  until i = 3 then print "ABC"
- So far we haven't gotten beyond the line permute(data, i+1, length)
- *I don't understand* why the program then jumps to the permute(data...) line after printing the line "ABC", we are in the
  "IF" not "ELSE" arm of the "if-else" clause.
- I then don't understand how we iterate between all characters using
  "i" and "j".

Does this make sense? 
Please can someone explain how this code yields all solutions. Thanks

```
def permute(data, i, length): 
    if i==length: 
        print(''.join(data) )
    else: 
        for j in range(i,length): 
            #swap
            data[i], data[j] = data[j], data[i] 
            permute(data, i+1, length) 
            data[i], data[j] = data[j], data[i]  


string = "ABC"
n = len(string) 
data = list(string) 
permute(data, 0, n)
```

Comment: The best way to understand recursion is to pretend it doesn't happen.  Just think of separate ('accidentally' same named) routines doing all the work.  Simpler?

Comment: Even though this isn't a particularly deep recursion, this function is far from a good candidate to learn how recursion works. The function isn't being "re-run" by recursive calls, a new instance of the function is being run **on top of** the existing instance. This _stacking_ of function calls is referred to as...well... **the stack**. When the if statement evaluates to True, we call this the **base case** of the recursive function, it exits and then the instance of the function which called it continues to run to completion, and then on down the stack. I recommend a different algorithm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's break down the code, line by line.  We're going to step from the start of the string to the end, incrementing `i` on each call.  Within each call, we iterate `j` over the remainder of the string.

```
def permute(data, i, length): 
    # If "i" is at the end, we're done with one permutation: print the result.
    if i==length: 
        print(''.join(data) )

    else:
        # for each remaining character (later in the string)
        for j in range(i,length):

            # Swap that character with the "ith" character
            data[i], data[j] = data[j], data[i]

            # Keeping data[0:i] fixed,
            # generate all permutations of the remainder of the string
            permute(data, i+1, length)

            # Swap the characters back
            data[i], data[j] = data[j], data[i]
```

Now, add a little basic instrumentation to trace the execution: trace routine entry and recursion; indent every time you recur.

```
indent = ""

def permute(data, i, length): 
    global indent
    print(indent, "ENTER", ''.join(data), i)
    indent += "  "

    if i==length: 
        print("PERMUATATION:", ''.join(data) )
    else: 
        for j in range(i,length): 
            print(indent, "SWAP", i, j)
            #swap
            data[i], data[j] = data[j], data[i] 
            permute(data, i+1, length) 
            data[i], data[j] = data[j], data[i]  

    indent = indent[2:]


string = "ABC"
n = len(string) 
data = list(string) 
permute(data, 0, n)
```

OUTPUT:

```
 ENTER ABC 0
   SWAP 0 0
   ENTER ABC 1
     SWAP 1 1
     ENTER ABC 2
       SWAP 2 2
       ENTER ABC 3
PERMUATATION: ABC
     SWAP 1 2
     ENTER ACB 2
       SWAP 2 2
       ENTER ACB 3
PERMUATATION: ACB
   SWAP 0 1
   ENTER BAC 1
     SWAP 1 1
     ENTER BAC 2
       SWAP 2 2
       ENTER BAC 3
PERMUATATION: BAC
     SWAP 1 2
     ENTER BCA 2
       SWAP 2 2
       ENTER BCA 3
PERMUATATION: BCA
   SWAP 0 2
   ENTER CBA 1
     SWAP 1 1
     ENTER CBA 2
       SWAP 2 2
       ENTER CBA 3
PERMUATATION: CBA
     SWAP 1 2
     ENTER CAB 2
       SWAP 2 2
       ENTER CAB 3
PERMUATATION: CAB
```

Now trace through the code with this information.